# Annotator.js adding custom http header to search and create methods

Tags: javascript, http, header, annotations, annotatorjs

Im using Annotator.js 1.2.0 and I need to add some custom HTTP headers to the POST and GET requests annotator does (create, search).

Is there an option I can set for that?